# DLL.NET with Com interrop behaviors differently if loaded by IIS 6.0 or by a VB6-built object

Tags: .net, iis, vb6, com-interop, aspose

I'm struggling with a very curious phenomenon.

I'm working with a legacy web application running on IIS 6.0 SP2, and I wanted to get it able to use a .NET API (Aspose.Words).

I wrote a COM-visible .NET DLL which I can use both with IIS with `CreateObject("MyDll.MyClass")` and a binary built with VB6 like DLL or an executable (with `CreateObject` or a static project reference to the TypeLib).

The weird part is that I experience a **different behavior** depending on the loading source. A process can **succeed** if the .NET dll is **called** from a **VB6 binary** and **fails** if from **IIS**.

Same code, same input, output differs.

My question is : **do IIS and VB6 binaries handle differently COM Visible DLL loading?**

---

I don't really see any MCVE sample I could produce. The COM-Visible class is exposed through the trivial following lines:

```vb
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> Public Interface IComObject
  Sub processSomething(docPath as String)
  ' [...]
End Interface
```

Also the failing process is very specific to the wrapped API.

```vb
Private Function retrieveTOCEntries(ByVal doc As Words.Document, ByVal documentBodyFileURL As String) As TocEntry()
    Dim entries As List(Of TocEntry) = New List(Of TocEntry)
    For Each field As Words.Fields.Field In doc.Range.Fields
        If Not field.Type.Equals(Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldType.FieldPageRef) Then Continue For
        Dim pageRef As Words.Fields.FieldPageRef = CType(field, Words.Fields.FieldPageRef)
        If pageRef.BookmarkName Is Nothing OrElse Not pageRef.BookmarkName.StartsWith("_Toc") Then Continue For
        Dim tocItem As Words.Paragraph = CType(field.Start.GetAncestor(Words.NodeType.Paragraph), Words.Paragraph)
        field.Remove()
        ' Here the change: b could be Nothing with IIS
        ' and not Nothing with a VB6 binary for the same input
        Dim b As Words.Bookmark = doc.Range.Bookmarks(pageRef.BookmarkName)
    End For
End Function
```

I solved my problem by checking the nothingness of `b`, but I'm still confused about this...

Comment: Question - when it fails in IIS, what kind of failure is it? An error?

Comment: Also, how does the second code block relate to the first?

Comment: Have you ensured you are running in 32 bit mode?

Comment: @DaveInCaz: "b" became for an unexpected reason Nothing (unexpected = does not occur when ran from a binary) at a given time of the loop, then an Exception is raised since the code tried to dereference it. The second block is a private Function called by `processSomething()`, directly or not.

Comment: @tcarvin, yes it's Windows 2008 Server 32 bit.